# Making a query to the DB using same parameters of loop

Tags: loop, query, mysql, sql

So, I have a loop that works great.

But I need to count how many posts that loop has, and I need to do it via a query to the DB.

My loop looks like:

```
$adsArg = array(
    'offset'             => $offset,
    'post_type'          => 'ads',
    'meta_key'           => $metaKey,
    'tax_query'          => $taxQuery,
    'meta_query'         => $metaValue,
);
$adsQuery = new WP_Query($adsArg);
```

And the query I have so far looks like:

```
$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'ads' AND post_status = 'publish' AND tax_query = " . $taxQuery . " AND meta_query = " . $metaValue . ", array() ) );
```

It's not working and I have no idea the proper way to do that.

The counter has to be done this way, with a direct query to the database.

Comment: what's the context? why would you do the same query twice?

Comment: Hey David. I have to, because for some reason the post_count is not working. I'm gonna try your solution tomorrow and see if it works. Thnx in advance.

Comment: `post_count` should work, you should be trying to fix that problem not come up with a complicated workaround like querying the database twice. What isn't working about post_count?

Comment: It just doesn't count anything.
The problem is, for this project, I can't touch the loop. The other guy did it, it is working, the posts are all retrieved. I have no idea if there is something else messing with the code before I use the post_count. But since I have to implement a small verification, I thought it would be faster to do that way. And the project owner is ok with that.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I found the problem and the solution. Thnx for pointing that I should try to fix it. I didn't have to touch the other code, just change the command. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of posts you can do it easily without a second query with

```
$adsQuery->post_count;
```

But if there's some reason (I'd love to know the context!) I can't grasp that the same query has to be run twice and to the database directly- to answer your question as to why it's not working:

- Has `$table_name` been defined? Are you using `{$wpdb->prefix}_posts` or `{$wpdb->posts}` in `$table_name`?
- You have no sql string value quotes around `$taxQuery` or `$metaValue` values, so that'll break the query, unless they integers
- Has `$wpdb` has been globally declared?
- Are you using `$wpdb->print_error()` to show the issue?
- If you echo'ed the string query instead of running it, do it look like you expect? whats missing? if you paste it in phpmyAdmin/sqlworkbench does it give you any indication of the problem?
- do you have any errors in your servers errors logs? mysql error logs?

---

I would suggest something like the following

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$query = "
    SELECT COUNT(ID) 
    FROM   {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE  post_type = 'ads' 
           AND post_status = 'publish' 
           AND tax_query = \"%s\"
           AND meta_query = \"%s\"";

// show query
// echo "<pre>{$query}</pre>";

$count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
    $query, 
    $taxQuery,
    $metaValue
));



echo "<pre>";
if($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
   echo " ERROR: ";
   $wpdb->print_error();
} else {
   echo "Count: {$count}";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hey David, thnx for the answer. Your code worked, but since you talked about the post_count and Jacob pointed that I should make post_count work... I searched and found taht post_count gets the posts found in the query including the 'post per page'. But I need to get all the posts inside the query, so I had to use found_posts.
I'm gonna accept your answer, since my question didn't explained that little detail. And I'm gonna post my solution as an answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Since I left out a detail in my question, I approved David Sword's answer because it helped me connect correctly to my DB the way I asked.

But in my specific case, the 'post_count' didn't work because it considers the 'offset' and 'post per page' attr.

Since I need all the posts in the query, I had to use 'found_posts'.

Ex.: $adsQuery->found_posts;

> This hook is especially useful when developing custom pagination. For instance, if you are declaring a custom offset value in your queries, WordPress will NOT deduct the offset from the the $wp_query->found_posts parameter (for example, if you have 45 usable posts after an offset of 10, WordPress will ignore the offset and still give found_posts a value of 55).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/found_posts

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Thnx also to @JacobPeattie for pointing that I should be trying to fix 'post_count' problem.